# PHP and HTML: How do I display one result one at a time?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am a newbie to PHP and HTML. I am running to this problem. How do I display one question at a time until the user chooses the answer and goes to the next question? My code right now displays all the questions on a same page. I just want the page display one question, the user chooses the answer and clicks the submit button to go to the next questions. Thank you so much !

```
    <?php
require_once 'database.php';

// Start the session
session_start();

$query = "SELECT * FROM question_table";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$question = $statement->fetchall();
//print_r($question); //test the query to see if any result comes back
$statement->closeCursor(); 

// Getting response from the student
//if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
//   
//echo "worked"; 
//echo $_POST["option"];
//}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>SimulationQuestion</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<form action="QuestionAndOption.php" method="POST">
<!--         index is used to display question number-->
        <?php $index =1; ?>
<!--        Pulling data from the returned array from the query-->
        <?php foreach($question as $value){ ?>
        Question <?php echo $index.": ".$value["Question"];?><br>

        A: <input type="radio" name="option" value="OptionA"> <?php echo $value["OptionA"]; ?><br>
        B: <input type="radio" name="option" value="OptionB"> <?php echo $value["OptionB"]; ?><br>
        C: <input type="radio" name="option" value="OptionC"> <?php echo $value["OptionC"]; ?><br>
        D: <input type="radio" name="option" value="OptionD"> <?php echo $value["OptionD"]; ?><br>

        <!--Submit button-->
        <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button><br>

        <!--index is increment by 1 after each loop-->
        <?php $index++; ?>                           
        <?php } ?>

    </form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM question_table WHERE id = 1` to get only the first question, then just increase the number as the user answers. This can be done in many different ways, like incrementing $_GET['question'] in an url like this: yourpage.com/questions.php?question=1

Comment: You could also do it with JavaScript on the client side, and send the results to the server using AJAX, which will give your page a more modern Single Page Application feel.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this but my answer would depend on if you want to save the answer to each question as the user goes through them? If so, then you would as suggested above need to have a hidden input on each form and output the current order number. Otherwise if you don't need to save you could simply output all questions and show/hide them with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the questions and a counter to store which question has been asked in `$_SESSION['questions']`. Use the counter (also stored in the `$_SESSION`) to figure out what the next question is and increment it after each submit.

To do this check after `session_start();` if `$_SESSION['questions']` is set. If not get your questions and store them into `$_SESSION['questions]` and set the counter to 0.

Instead of the `foreach()` you access your questions by `$_SESSION['questions'][$_SESSION['counter']]` but do not forget to increase the counter each time.

---

Sample code:

The part to set set / get the questions and increase the counter:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['questions'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM question_table";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $question = $statement->fetchall();
    $statement->closeCursor();

    $_SESSION['questions'] = $question;
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    // DO YOUR STUFF

    $_SESSION['counter']++;
}
?>
```

The part the output the question:

```
<?php
    $question = $_SESSION['questions'][$_SESSION['counter']];
    if(empty($question)) {
        // FINISHED ALL QUESTIONS
    } else {
?>
<form action="QuestionAndOption.php" method="POST">
    Question <?php echo $_SESSION['counter'] . ": " . $question["Question"]; ?><br>

    A: <input type="radio" name="option" value="OptionA"> <?php echo $question["OptionA"]; ?><br>
    B: <input type="radio" name="option" value="OptionB"> <?php echo $question["OptionB"]; ?><br>
    C: <input type="radio" name="option" value="OptionC"> <?php echo $question["OptionC"]; ?><br>
    D: <input type="radio" name="option" value="OptionD"> <?php echo $question["OptionD"]; ?><br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
    } // if close 
?>
```

Comment: Valiant effort, but a question of this level requires a much more robust example of the code to use to make this work.  A small, working example, would be necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I just want to understand the code.In the code, where in the code that makes the page display the next question after I answer one and click the submit? $question["Question"] automatically goes to the next question after each submit? Thanks

Comment: Is it because of the multidimensional array? $question = $_SESSION['questions'][$_SESSION['counter']];

Comment: @Nathan: Yes, it is because of the `$question = $_SESSION['questions'][$_SESSION['counter']];`. The first time you call the script it will init the questions key and set the counter key to zero. Submitting the form leads to sending the form data to "QuestionAndOption.php" by POST. This leads PHP to set `$_POST["submit"]`. If `$_POST["submit"]` is set, `$_SESSION['counter']` will be increased by 1. By `$question = $_SESSION['questions'][$_SESSION['counter']];` `$question` stores now the next question and uses the new values to populate the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one page that displays one question. Your query would be: `SELECT * FROM question_table WHERE Question = :id`. You would then do `$statement = $db->prepare($query, array(":id" => $_GET["id"]))` to prepare the query to get only one question, fetch the question and then display the question fetched by the database.

After the user answered the question, it will be submitted and in your submission logic, it should redirect the user to the next question, simply by incrementing the question id. The page address should have a query parameter called `id` (like: `mypage.php?id=1`).

Pastebin: [Here](http://pastebin.com/LeyXMHaL)